# Is the process $X_t$ in the Doob's uniform approximation lemma a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I am studying a proof of Doob-Meyer decomposition in Kallenberg's "Foundations of Modern Probability", which goes by a discrete approximation based on Dunford's characterisation of weak compactness, combined with Doob's approximation of inaccessible times. The setting is that of a right-continuous and complete filtration on $R_+$.

I have a problem with a gap in the proof of the latter, which is (in 1997 ed.; 10.8 in 2021 ed.):

**Lemma 22.8** *(approximation of inaccessible times, Doob)*
$\qquad$*For a totally inaccessible time $\tau$, put $\tau_n=2^{-n}[2^n\tau]$, and let $X^n$ be a right-continuous version of the process $P\{\tau_n\le t|\mathcal{F}_t\}$. Then*
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{t\ge 0} \left| X^n_t - 1\{\tau\le t\} \right| = 0 \;\; a.s.
$$

Now, as the Author's hint is to use optional sampling to fill a gap in the proof, I wonder if one can show that $X^n$ is a martingale; also the proof of the next lemma (on accessibility of jumps) suggests that this is the case.

Here is my line of thought.
Take $n=0$, so that $\tau_0=[\tau]$ (for positive  $n$ we scale by $2^n$).
Note that $X^0_t$ is a martingale iff so is $1-X^0_t=Y_t=P\{ \tau_0 > t | \mathcal{F}_t \}$.  Now, $\tau_0$ takes only integer values.
If we take $t\in[0,1)$, we have
$$
\{\tau_0 > t\} = \{ \tau_0 \ge 1 \} = \{ \tau \ge 1 \},
\qquad\text{so}\quad
Y_t = P\{ \tau \ge 1 | \mathcal{F}_t \}.
$$
So far, so good: on $[0,1)$, $Y_t$ is a martingale. What about $t$ crossing $1$? Is
$$
Y_t = E\,[Y_1 |\mathcal{F}_t] \; a.\!s. \quad \text{for}\; t\in[0,1)?
$$
By definition, $Y_1=P\{ \tau_0 > 1 | \mathcal{F}_1 \}=P\{ \tau\ge2 | \mathcal{F}_1 \}$,
so $E\,[Y_1 |\mathcal{F}_t] = P\{ \tau\ge2 | \mathcal{F}_t \}$.

So, the question is:
If $\tau$ is totally inaccessible, do we have
$$
P\{\tau\ge 1 | \mathcal{F}_t\} = P\{\tau\ge 2 | \mathcal{F}_t\} \; a.\!s.  \quad\text{for}\;\; t\in[0,1)?
$$